# Column not found: unknown column

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I am trying to insert information in the database. And i have the error

> column not found:  Unknown column 'updated_at' in 'field list'

I donot have that column in my database.

model

```
<?php

namespace App;

class quiz extends Basemodel {

    protected $primaryKey = 'qid';
    protected $table = 'quiz';
    protected $fillable = array('question', 'opt1', 'opt2','opt3','opt4','answer','category', 'level');

}
```

controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
  {
    $input =$request->all();
    $q=new quiz();
    $q->question=$input['question'];
    $q->answer=$input['answer'];
    $q->opt1=$input['opt1'];
    $q->opt2=$input['opt2'];
    $q->opt3=$input['opt3'];
    $q->save();

 }
```

Comment: And does your model have the `timestamp` property defined as false?

Comment: @MarkBaker just set. but same error persist.

Answer (score 0):

set `public $timestamp = false;` in your model

Comment: `public $timestamps = false;` that it is.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as Adam mentioned,

Set `public $timestamp = false;` in your model

Or else, add this line in the Model file.

```
protected $hidden = ['updated_at'];
```

Comment: `public $timestamps = false;` that it is.